# How to detect trivial destructor at compile time?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I have a templated container class that looks something like this:

```
template <class ItemType> class MyContainer
{
public:
   [... various methods omitted for brevity...]

   void Clear()
   {
      ItemType defaultItem;
      for (int i=0; i<_numValidItems; i++) _itemArray[i] = defaultItem;
      _numValidItems = 0;
   }

   void FastClear()
   {
      _numValidItems = 0;
   }

private:
   int _numValidItems;
   ItemType * _itemArray;
};
```

As you can see, the Clear() method resets each item in the container to its default state, which is necessary for types where e.g. the individual items have dynamically allocated internal resources that I want the Clear() call to release.

There is also the FastClear(), which as the name implies is faster (O(1) instead of O(N)) because it simply sets _numValidItems to zero, and doesn't actually touch any of the items in the array.  This is great for POD-style ItemTypes, but not so good for e.g. file-handle types.

My question is, is there a way to use SFINAE or similar to get the compiler to decide at compile time that it is safe to make Clear() a synonym for FastClear(), i.e. when ItemType has a trivial destructor?  That way the calling code wouldn't have to remember to call FastClear() instead of Clear to get a speedup, it would work automatically.

Also, just to make things more difficult... I'd like to be able to do this without adding a dependency to Boost/TR1/C++11.  (so calling is_pod() or has_trivial_destructor() aren't good options for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for [Boost Type Traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) together with [enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html). I think it quite closely answers your question. If you don't want the includes, you can always implement it yourself, using Boost for the inspiration. It uses SFINAE after all.

Answer (score 5):

The proper way to call the destructor is

```
void Clear()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _numValidItems; ++ i)
    {
        _itemArray[i].~ItemType();
    }
    _numValidItems = 0;
}
```

The optimizer on gcc 4.6 (at -O2 or above) will eliminate the loop when the destructor is trivial (not sure about 4.2, you check it yourself). For instance, with ItemType equals to `std::pair<double, double>`, your version of Clear() produces

```
0000000000000000 <_ZN11MyContainerISt4pairIddEE8BadClearEv>:
   0:   8b 0f                   mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [rdi]
   2:   85 c9                   test   ecx,ecx
   4:   7e 34                   jle    3a <_ZN11MyContainerISt4pairIddEE8BadClearEv+0x3a>
   6:   83 e9 01                sub    ecx,0x1
   9:   48 8b 57 08             mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rdi+0x8]
   d:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
   f:   48 83 c1 01             add    rcx,0x1
  13:   48 c1 e1 04             shl    rcx,0x4
  17:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nop    WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
  1e:   00 00 
  20:   48 c7 04 02 00 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rdx+rax*1],0x0
  27:   00 
  28:   48 c7 44 02 08 00 00    mov    QWORD PTR [rdx+rax*1+0x8],0x0
  2f:   00 00 
  31:   48 83 c0 10             add    rax,0x10
  35:   48 39 c8                cmp    rax,rcx
  38:   75 e6                   jne    20 <_ZN11MyContainerISt4pairIddEE8BadClearEv+0x20>
  3a:   c7 07 00 00 00 00       mov    DWORD PTR [rdi],0x0
  40:   c3                      ret
```

while my version produces

```
0000000000000000 <_ZN11MyContainerISt4pairIddEE5ClearEv>:
   0:   c7 07 00 00 00 00       mov    DWORD PTR [rdi],0x0
   6:   c3                      ret
```

---

And since gcc 4.2 already bundles with TR1, I don't know why you can't use `std::tr1::has_trivial_destructor`.